# Read file and check dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to read a file line by line and check for each line whether one string of the line is allowed by my dictionary to be with another string in the same line. I have come up with this code

```
dic={'ALA':['N','H','CA','HA','CB','HB1','HB2','HB3','C','O'],
'GLY':['N','H','CA','HA2','HA3','C','O'],
(...)
}

fin=open('file.pdb','r')

for line in fin:
    atom=line[12:16].strip()
    resi=line[17:20].strip()
    if atom not in dic[resi]:
        print(line)
```

But it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "names.py", line 38, in <module>
if atom not in dic[resi]:
KeyError: '3.2'
```

So this is not working. Strangely replacing dic[resi] to something like dic['ALA'] works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: give us snippet of `file.pdb`, even somehting like 2-3 lines will suffice

Comment: Clearly, whatever is being read at `line[17:20].strip()` is 3.2, which isn't a residue. It's impossible to tell without seeing the nature of the file.

Comment: It just tells you that there's no key with the name `3.2` in `dic`. Maybe your slicing gives wrogn results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're getting the value of `3.2` for `resi` for one of the lines and since `3.2` is not a valid key in dic, you're getting an exception.

```
for line in fin:
    atom=line[12:16].strip()
    resi=line[17:20].strip()
    if resi in dic and atom not in dic[resi]:
        print(line)
```

EDIT:

```
for line in fin:
    atom=line[12:16].strip()
    resi=line[17:20].strip()
    if resi in dic.keys() and atom not in dic[resi]:
        print(line)
```

The first method using the `n` keyword is the best way to know the existence of a key in a dictionary. It runs in O(1)(uses hashing) while the second method does a linear search after getting the keys of the dictionary.

In both the methods, since short-circuiting is used, if the first condition fails, the second condition would never get evaluated. Alternatively you can rescue the exception using `try..except` block.

For reference, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Amazing! I was not aware that my file header had some lines in the beginning which are different. Thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a key named '3.2' in `dic`. I think you should check the key name first.

```
for line in fin:
    atom=line[12:16].strip()
    resi=line[17:20].strip()
    result = dic.get(resi)
    if result and (atom not in result):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It says Keyerror when you use dic[resi] because 'resi' is not a key in the dic but 'ALA'  is a key in your dictionary. If you try something like print (dic['ALA']) it will print everything under the 'ALA' key.